# Splitting of a topological vector space (TVS) into an (a) countable sum and (b) direct integral of subspaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I thought that this would be a simpe question, and placed it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4371932/splitting-of-a-topological-vector-space-tvs-into-an-a-countable-sum-and-b) at the Mathematics Stackexchange. Now have to elevate it to Mathoverflow.

---

LANGUAGE

TVS = topological vector space. Any subspace of a TVS is a TVS in the induced-topology sense.

DEFINITION

For TVS spaces ${\mathbb{V}}_1\subset\mathbb V$, a TVS subspace ${\mathbb{V}}_2\subset\mathbb V$ is a *topological complement* of ${\mathbb{V}}_1$ in $\mathbb V$, if $\mathbb V$ is their direct sum both algebraically and topologically. This implies that
$$
 {\mathbb{V}}_1\oplus {\mathbb{V}}_2\,=\,{\mathbb{V}}~\,,
 $$
and the following addition map is a homeomorphism:
$$
 {\mathbb{V}}_1\times{\mathbb{V}}_2\,\longrightarrow\,{\mathbb{V}}~~,\qquad
 \left(\, v\in{{\mathbb V}}_1\,,~\,v^{\,\prime}\in{{\mathbb V}}_2\,\right)\,\longmapsto~ (v+v^{\,\prime})\in\mathbb V~~.\\
 $$

QUESTION A

For a *COUNTABLY* infinite splitting
$$
{\mathbb V}=\bigoplus_{i\in\cal I}{\mathbb V}_i
$$
to be not only algebraic but also topological, would it be sufficient to impose the condition that a natural map
$$
\bigoplus \mathbb{V}_i\longrightarrow\mathbb{V}
$$
exists and is a homeomorphism?

Here $\bigoplus \mathbb{V}_i$ is a set of all families $\left(\mathbb{v}_i\right)_{i\in\cal I}$ with $v_i\in {\mathbb V}_i$ and only finitely many non-zero $v_i$.
$~~~~~\\\\$

QUESTION B

Would this work also for an uncountable sum (direct integral) of subspaces?

Stated alternatively, can we always be sure that there always exists a necessary measure on the set of these subspaces?

If there is no general answer to question B, can this question be answered for Hilbert spaces?$~~~~~\\\\$

KIND REQUEST

This question is of interest mainly to physicists. Could you please make your answer sufficiently detailed and, if possible, understandable to a layman? Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain what is "the map $\{\mathbb{V}_i\}_{i\in I}\rightarrow \mathbb{V} $"?

Comment: I guess that you mean by $\bigoplus V_i$ the set of all families $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ with $v_i\in V_i$ and only finitely many non-zero $v_i$. Then there is a natural map $\bigoplus V_i \to V$, $(v_i)_{i\in I}\mapsto \sum v_i$. If you want this map to be a homeomrphism, you need a topology on the direct sum. If you insist to work in TVS, the natural one would be the finest vector space topology on $\bigoplus V_i$ such that all inclusions $V_j\to \bigoplus V_i$, $v_j\mapsto (v_i)_{i\in I}$ with all $v_i=0$ for $i\neq j$ are continuous. (This is indeed the *coproduct* in the category TVS.) ...

Comment: With this interpretation, infinite dimensional Banach spaces never split into a (countable) sum of $V_i\neq \{0\}$.

Comment: @abx My statement about the map was indeed obscure, but fortunately, Jochen Wengenroth in his comment explained this point in more detail. I will now make a correction in my question, to clarify this.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Many thanks! Both of your comments are extremely useful. You are saying that an infinite-dimensional Banach space will never split into a countable sum sum of spaces ${\mathbb V}_i$. Are you talking about a Banach space of uncountable dimensions? Can it be split into an uncountable sum? Also, how about a countable-dim Banach space?

Comment: Maybe of interest to you: https://www.planetmath.org/banachspacesofinfinitedimensiondonothaveacountablehamelbasis

Comment: @user7427029 Thank you for the link. I see that an infinite-dim Banach does not possess a countable Hamel basis. Does it always posses an uncountable one? If yes, would this warrant that a Banach can always split into a direct integral of subspaces?

Comment: (a) For example in Hilbert space, you want countable direct sum decomposition $\oplus V_i$ to consist of sequences $v_i \in V_i$ with $\sum \|v_i\|^2 <+\infty$.  (b) I do not know a definition of "direct integral" other than in Hilbert space. (c) Even in Hilbert space, you may want direct integral **with respect to** a measure, so that countable direct sum is automatically included, no need for separate cases.  For help on this setting, see the mathematical formulation of the spectral theorem.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thanks for your comment. And yes, I also saw direct integral only in the Hilbert space context. So my Question A remains in force, for a general-type Banach space.

Comment: The *Hilbert space direct sum* described by Gerald Edgar is the categrorical direct sum for the category of Hilbert spaces and linear **contractions** as morphisms (sometimescalled *short maps*), this works similarly in the category of Banach spaces and linear contractions where $\bigoplus V_i$ is the spaces of $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ such that $\sum_i \|v_i\| <\infty$.

Comment: ... so Hilbert space is never the infinite direct sum $\oplus V_i$ in the $l^1$ sense mentioned by @JochenWengenroth . A nontrivial infinite $l^1$ direct sum is never reflexive.  Von Neumann's "direct integral" was not so much for Hilbert spaces alone but more for operators on Hilbert space.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Could you please advise me a reference on this? Preferably, a simple textbook, not a serious monograph.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Now I am lost. Above, you told me that, yes, a Hilbert space permits for a countable direct sum $\oplus V_i$ consisting of sequences $v_i\in V_i$ with $\sum||v_i||^2 < \infty$. And now you are saying that a Hilbert space is never an infinite direct sum in the $l^1$ sense. What is $l^1$ sense? Also, is my understanding correct that a Banach space can be split into an infinite sum consisting of vectors obeying $\sum||v_i||^2 < \infty$ ? (For the needs of a physicist that would be sufficient.)

Comment: The $l^1$ direct sum takes sequences $v_i \in V_i$ with $\sum \|v_i\|<+\infty$, as described by @JochenWengenroth .  Some Banach spaces can be split that way, but not Hilbert space.  For Hilbert space, take the $l^2$ direct sum where you use $\sum \|v_i\|^2 < + \infty$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thank you! This is really helpful. Could you please give me a reference on this?